# How to design the form, for an admin, for approving or rejecting changes?

Tags: usability

I have the following scenario - in my web application each user can update their profile. But before their profile goes live, an admin goes through the changes of each field and approves/rejects a change. Now, there are 28 fields which a user can update. When an admin reviews the changes, I am thinking there will be 4 columns, a table - field name, original value, new value (submitted by the user) and another column with action to approve or reject. If a change of a field value is approved it goes live on their profile page. Can there be a better design? There are some columns which are images; so the admin should see both original and the new image. Also, the admin should be able to edit the changes submitted by the user ( so, I will have to display values in textboxes ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggestion will have a variable structure that will depend from changes made, also the administrator will not have the full profile when reviewing.

Consider the following option :

- Keep the structure of the form exactly as filled by the user
- Next to each field that is changed add two small icons, a red X for reject and a green tick for accept. The icons will be visible only for fields changed.
- When an option is made (accepted or rejected), highlight the background of the respective icon.
- Make the fields editable to allow changes.
- When the mouse is over the changed field, display just above the old value. When the mouse leaves the field, hide the old value. Something like a tooltip. Apply the same for the image as well.
- Add a submit changes at the bottom of the screen.